# calling self.class.where() in a transaction, but the records i'm trying to select are ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using an `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` to make a whole bunch of calls pertaining to a grouping of objects that must update/create simultaneously or not at all. One method in this transaction is supposed to use `where` to find and delete all `Trades` that match certain parameters.

```
class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base
 include Discard::Model

 belongs_to :trade_requester, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :wanted_share, class_name: "Share"

 validates :trade_requester, :wanted_share, presence: true
 validates :amount, presence: true

 def new_wanted_total
  wanted_share.amount - amount
 end

 def update_wanted_share_amount(new_wanted_total)
  wanted_share.update_attribute(:amount, new_wanted_total)
 end

 def delete_extraneous_wanted_trades(wanted_share)
  self.class.where("wanted_share_id = ? AND amount > ? AND approved_at = ? AND discarded_at = ?", wanted_share.id, new_wanted_total, nil, nil).delete_all
 end

 def accept
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
   delete_extraneous_wanted_trades(wanted_share)
   update_wanted_share_amount(new_wanted_total) if new_wanted_total >= 0
   Share.create(user_id: self.trade_requester.id, item_id: self.wanted_share.item.id, amount: self.amount, active: false)
   self.touch(:approved_at)
  end
 end
end
```

When I `accept` and check the output in my terminal, one line I get says this:

```
SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "trades" WHERE (wanted_share_id = 8 AND amount > 25 AND approved_at = NULL AND discarded_at = NULL).
```

I am passing the correct information to the method, and the rest of the terminal output shows that the related records have been updated with the appropriate attributes (one `Share` set to `amount:25` and another `Share` created with `amount:50`). But then I check my database, and it says that there is still one `Trade` for `amount: 60`. This record exceeds the available total, which is now 50 (it was previously 75), and should have been deleted. But according to the terminal output, it was ignored. Why did this record go untouched?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` is used by default when `save` or `destroy` is called on individual records. However, if you need to update multiple records in one go or not at all, the entire thing should be wrapped in a transaction. In this particular case, I am updating a `Trade`, updating a `Share`, creating a new `Share`, and, if necessary, deleting other `Trades`.

Comment: Have you tried writing any tests for your code?

Comment: also when you say `"But then I check my database, and it says that there is still one Trade for amount: 60", how are you checking?  It also sounds like you could have race conditions.  Can you use callbacks?

Comment: i'm doing all my testing manually because i don't have the time to learn the rspec api from the ground up at this point in time. i am also checking my database manually. i am wrapping my code in a transaction to avoid race conditions. by "callbacks" do you mean that i should consider placing some of that code into a callback as opposed to a transaction?

Comment: You can learn the basics of mini test in 15 minutes, you'll surely lose way more time trying to debug the way you're going. You've been warned.  https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest

Comment: can whoever did it please not spitefully downvote my question? it's a valid q, and i've provided work to show that i'm not just asking others to do my work for me. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`approved_at = ? AND discarded_at = ?` in the where clause should be `approved_at IS NULL AND discarded_at IS NULL`